# Trying to move a subsite under another parent give me a generic error "File not found"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I'm trying to move a subsite under another parent using `sitemanager.aspx`, but I can't. 
The error I get is

> Something went wrong. File not found

I can't-do for any site/subsite. I don't know what to do.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What's the current SharePoint Edition ? and the current Sie Template

Answer (score 3):

You should be aware of the `sitemanager.aspx` or `Content and Structure` is available at **Publishing site** or site with **Publishing Feature** activated.

Any hacking to the site URL `_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx` to open the `Content and Structure` will not be working properly and you will get `File Not Found` error

[image]

---

The available workaround is activating the **Publishing Feature** as the following:

- Activate `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` at the site collection feature.

[image]

- Activate `SharePoint Server Publishing` at the site feature.

[image]

> **But** you should be aware of activating these features will lead to
>   missing the `Save site as a template`. For more details check [MISSING
>   SAVE SITE AS TEMPLATE IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)